# jQuery - fadeIn object after page reload

Tags: jquery

I have an Ajax based form with 3 radio buttons. When one is checked, div1 fadeIn, if two is checked, div1 fadeOut, div2 fadeIn etc. This part works great.

But I also have success and error notification in those forms, which are not disappearing when radio buttons are switched, so for div2 you can see errors from div1.

I know that I could rename the success and error box classes for each form, but I'm wondering, is there a way I could reload the page or reset the form when switching radio buttons and then needed content would fadeIn? I tried to use `location.reload()` but it just reloads the whole page, and needed div never fadeIn.

Hope someone could help, I'm a jQuery n00b, but I'm really starting to like this framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquerys `hide` function to hide the notification divs when the radios are clicked:

html:

```
<div class="notification">There is an error</div>
```

script:

```
function onRadioClick() {
    ("div.notification").hide();
    // Do your fade in stuff

}
```

If I got your question right?

Comment: Yes it works, but in this case after message is successful in div1, and I switch to div2 and then back to div1, then the div1 is completely empty, how could I leave success msg only in that form?

Comment: Ok, I guess this is the only reasonably solution for this. Thank you!

Comment: you should have some form of validation function that displays the notification messages, right? Then you only have to run that function when the radio buttons are pressed to restore the state of the messages. To help more precise - start a new question for that and include your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your success/error area has an id of `messageArea`, inside your click script:

```
$('#messageArea').empty(); //Remove contents
//Put your error messages as you would, fade in and out and whatever you wish
```